# How is a smooth web page scrolling effect created in windows browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-plugins

I have seen a few themes that have managed to implement a nice smooth scrolling effect on web pages that you usually get with mac's and not windows based browsers:

http://themeforest.net/item/elantra-2015-elegant-personal-blogging-theme/full_screen_preview/10576274

http://demo.bossthemes.com/claudine_watches/

Can anyone enlighten me as to how this is best achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watch website is using this jQuery plugin: https://gist.github.com/salipro4ever/35ba6d9e61cade99a0c2